# easyxdm Put giving a 400 Bad request Error

Tags: ajax, jquery, put, easyxdm

I'm facing a problem with PUT request when using easyXDM. Other Operations such as POST, DELETE works fine.
Initially it was placing data in query string. Tried following another post: [easyXDM PUT places data in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337476/easyxdm-put-places-data-in-query-string)

After changing the code it is now sending the data in Request Payload but the data is not well formed, which is leading to the bad request.

```
putJson = function (url, request, success_callback, error_callback, custom_headers) {
        if (typeof (custom_headers) == "undefined") {
            custom_headers = {};
        };
        //custom_headers.Accept = "application/json";

        this.rpcSocket.request({
            url: url,
            method: "PUT",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}, 
            data: request
        },
        function (response) {
            success_callback(response);
        },
        function (error_response) {
            if (_.isUndefined(error_callback) || !_.isFunction(error_callback)) {
                ajaxError.call(error_response);
            }
            else {
                error_callback(error_response)
            };
        });
    }
```